# Изменение шрифта при печати на принтер

Tags: python, windows, печать

Нужно из python распечатать текстовый файл. Использую следующий код

```
import tempfile
import win32api
filename = tempfile.mktemp('.txt')
open(filename, 'w').write('Test')
win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'print', filename, None, '.', 0)
```

(пример взят отсюда [ссылка](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html)).

Всё печатает, но слишком крупно. Можно ли как-нибудь можно изменить шрифт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Системная команда `print` выполняет печать текстового файла путём запуска приложения по умолчанию для текстовых файлов (Блокнот). Данная команда не предоставляет возможности изменения шрифта (следовательно этого не умеет и модуль `win32api`).

Однако перед выводом на печать можно изменить **значение ключа**, отвечающего за величину шрифта, **в реестре Windows**. После печати заменить значение на исходное:

```
import tempfile
import win32api
import winreg
import time

def do_print():
    """ Исходный код вывода файла на принтер """
    filename = tempfile.mktemp('.txt')
    open(filename, 'w').write('Test')
    win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'print', filename, None, '.', 0)

with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Microsoft\\Notepad", 
                    access=winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as key:
    # Сохранить исходное значение величины шрифта
    value, typ = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "iPointSize")
    # Изменить размер шрифта - значение величины шрифта нужно умножить на 10
    winreg.SetValueEx(key, "iPointSize", 0, typ, 6*10)

    do_print()
    # Небольшой таймаут для запуска Блокнота
    time.sleep(3)       

    # Вернуть исходное значение
    winreg.SetValueEx(key, "iPointSize", 0, typ, value)
```

Тестировалось на Python 3.6, Windows 7 64-bit, PDF-принтер.